# Разметка сетки в Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть два варианта разметки, но какой из них правильный?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>

        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Или**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотря что тебе нужно получить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта верны. Все зависит от ситуации.
Даже в самой документации Bootstrap 4 есть пример где [используются колонки условной суммой большей 12ти](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match)

[image: Mix and Match]]

Есть [интересный материал (англ.)](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-exceed-12-columns-in-a-row-b551eeddf62b), где приведены пару примеров использования первого варианта, начинающим будет полезно.

Answer (score 1):

класс row- позволяет все блоки в одну строку подравнять.В данном случае 2-ой вариант правильный, так как максимум 12 сеток, и вы заполняете все 12. В 1 варианте вы пытаетесь в 12 сеток запихать 24 сеток , поэтому оно скатится вниз.(где md,sm,lg,xs)?